# Memory management using placement new

Tags: c++

Is it possible to use a single memory pool for multi type variables using placement new. I need integer and character variables to be declared in a single pool.

Shall I further divide the pool into 2 and then use it for the different variable types or there is some other approach?

Comment: Did you consider using unions for this?

`union { int i; char c; };`

Comment: wont a union be of 4 bytes even if i use it for characters thus wasting memory?

Comment: I doubt that the allocator will allocate less then four bytes, because of alignment issues.

Comment: @Saksham, it will be, but if you pack the variables as close as possible, you risk the chance of slow memory access and/or crashes due to bad alignment. Furthermore, I think you can't do this kind of unaligned access with only pointer casts without violating the strict aliasing of C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is yes, but this is generally only needed when you have some memory mapped IO (shared memory???).  AFAIK there is no speed increase gained.  Exactly what are you doing?

Have you considered using a 3rd party pool?  I found a really general implementation [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15527/C-Memory-Pool).

[Boost::pool](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/pool/doc/html/index.html) might also be interesting

Answer (score 2):

If your data types are variable length you are better using the standard heap for memory management. The standard heap is highly optimized for this use-case.

Using a memory pool generally only becomes useful when you are consistently allocating objects of the same size. It then becomes easy to divide your pool into equal sized cells are perform optimizations like free-lists that the system heap is unable to do.

Comment: I was writing a program to simulate an embedded project thus needed a memory pool rather than a standard heap